# Javascript how to find the position of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my first question here, so pardon me if I get something wrong.

I have an array of coordinates organized as objects, and I need to find and delete a certain object. I am stuck trying to get the position of the object with the specific x and y coordinates in the array.

Here is where I got to:

```
door_array = [{x:3, y:4},{x: 12,y: 12}, {x: 15,y:15}];

function remove_door(dx,dy, array) 
{
    var obj = {x:dx,y:dy};  
    var a = door_array.indexOf(obj); //this part doesn't work
    door_array.slice(a,1)   

}
```

When i try to call the function, it appears to read the array as [object,object,object], and returns -1.

The question is, how do I find the position of the specific object via it's coordinates so I can delete it?

Comment: the problem is that you are creating a new object (with the same values as the one you are looking for). This is not the same *object* though. You would probably need to filter by values or ad an id...

Comment: `{x: 4} === {x: 4} // false`

Comment: using indexOf( object ) compares by reference (or by pointers) that's why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through each object and delete them with `splice` method

```
door_array = [{x:3, y:4},{x: 12,y: 12}, {x: 15,y:15}];

function remove_door(dx,dy, arrays) 
{
    var obj = {x:dx,y:dy};
    for(i=0; i<arrays.length; i++){

    var a = arrays[i]; 

        if(a.x == obj.x && a.y == obj.y){
        console.log('found');
            arrays.splice(i,1);
        }

        }
    console.log(arrays);
    return arrays;


}
remove_door(12,12,door_array);
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkq0xg2/2/)** check your browser console

Comment: Thank you, I already got it to work from a previous answer, but will keep this method in mind.

Comment: Okay no problem. Check this. if you have any doubt, just ask me:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `obj` is a different object than the one in the list.  You should loop through the objects in the list till you find the one you need. Ex.

```
door_array = [{x:3, y:4},{x: 12,y: 12}, {x: 15,y:15}];

function remove_door(dx,dy, array) 
{
    var index = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i].x == dx && array[i].y == dy)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(index != -1)
    {
        array.slice(index,1);
    } 
    return array;
}
```

You should return array after you are done manipulating it.  Call like this:

```
door_array = remove_door(x, y, door_array);
```

Comment: the `if` body should operate on `array` that is passed as an argument, not on `door_array`

Comment: and you should return `array` since `slice` does not operate in place

Comment: Thank you very much for that(all who took the time to answer). it now returns the correct value(index), but for some reason it didn't delete the object from the array. I changed array.slice to array.splice, and now it works like it should, though I am not sure why slice didn't do it.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace indexOf with a loop that checks each element one at a time. That is effectively what is happening in the indexOf function, except that indexOf is doing a strict, triple-equals (===) equality check, which won't work for an object unless it is the exact same one.

```
var x = {};
var y = {};

y === x; // false
x === x; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` with object won't work for you.

I won't loop through all the array to find the object because it will be in complexity of O(n).

I would suggest to create a map with key as x_y and value as the object itself,
something like that should work for you:

```
var map = {};
map["3_4"] = {x:3, y:4};
map["2_12"] = {x:2, y:12};

// then you can get the value with O(1)
var requiredValue = map[dx + "_" + dy];
```

That's just my 2 cents.

Good luck anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As Mozilla [describes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) it:

> indexOf compares searchElement to elements of the Array using strict equality (the same method used by the ===, or triple-equals, operator).

And triple equals doesn't do deep object comparison, it compares by reference.
You can re-factor your code to this:

```
door_array = [{x:3, y:4},{x: 12,y: 12}, {x: 15,y:15}];

function remove_door(dx,dy, array) 
{
    var obj = {x:dx,y:dy};
    for (var i = 0; i < door_array.length; i++){
       if(door_array[i].x === obj.x && door_array[i].y === obj.y)
          return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```